# How to add markers dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I just need the markers in OpenLayers to change dynamically. I don't know how to do that..

for loop `console.debug(response.i)` output is

```
[Object { lat="36.15900011", lon="-115.17205183"}, 
 Object { lat="36.15899561", lon="-115.17276155"}]
```

Sorry for pasting the complete code here..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
      url:'parser', success:function(response){
        $(document).ready(function(){
          console.debug('hello')
          var jsonlen = response.length;
          for (var i=0; i<=jsonlen; i++){
            console.debug(response.i)
          }
          console.debug(response)
          // icon feature started
          var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            // empty vector
          })
          var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([80.2700, 13.0839], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
            name:'Null Island',
            population: 4000,
            rainfall:500
          })
          vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);

          //create the style
          var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon(/**@type {olx.style.IconOptions}*/({
              anchor: [0.5, 46],
              anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
              anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
              opacity: 0.75,
              src: 'http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/data/icon.png'
            }))
          });

          // add the feature vector to the layer vector, 
          // and apply a style to whole layer
          var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource,
            style: iconStyle
          });
          var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }), 
                     vectorLayer],
            target: document.getElementById('map'),
            view: new ol.View({
              center: [0, 0],
              zoom: 3
            })
          });


        })
      }
    })
</script>
```

above code the one marker is working fine

Comment: what kind of modification you want to do? change dynamically the position of each marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what your json represents it is difficult to parse your response. I would change the stucture of your code to create everything first and then in the ajax success handler either add new features to your source or clear the source and add the new features.

I am guessing that your response contains an array of features. In your example there are two point objects, the code below will assume that they are supposed to form a line that could be any length. If you actually pasted the whole response remove the second loop and just create point a point geometry to transform and pass in to the feature.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//create the source, layer, icon, map and view first

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
     // empty vector
})


//create the style
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/**@type {olx.style.IconOptions}*/({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        opacity: 0.75,
        src: 'http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/data/icon.png'
     }))
});

// and apply a style to whole layer
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: iconStyle
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }), 
        vectorLayer],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 3
    })
});

$.ajax({
    url:'parser', 
    success:function(response){
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var jsonlen = response.length;

            // a loop that handles each feature
            for (var i=0; i<=jsonlen; i++){
                console.debug(response.i)
                //now create your new feature here
                var coordinates = [];
                for (var j=0; j<response.i.length; j++){
                    //this loop adds the pairs of coordinates to an array to make our linestring geometry
                    coordinates.push(ol.proj.transform([+response.i.j.lon, +response.i.j.lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
                }
                var line = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
                var feature = new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: line,
                    id: i
                });
                vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
            }

        })
      }
    })
</script>
```

One final idea is that if you control the server why not pass proper GeoJSON, I use https://github.com/jmikola/geojson in PHP to create GeoJSON which can be read by the `ol.source.GeoJSON` source.

Comment: Two things here: 1) The coordinate passed to `ol.proj.transform` does not use the correct ordering, it should be `[lon, lat]`. 2) It is important to make sure that the values passed to `ol.proj.transform` are numbers, so it may be required to use `+response.i.j.lat` and `+response.i.j.lon` here.